# Как сделать, чтобы проверялись все пункты?

Tags: javascript

```
После ввода этого кода, проверяется только один вопрос, а хотелось чтобы проверялись все.
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
разметка HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
    <style>
        @import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400,600,700');
 
        *, *:before, *:after {margin: 0; padding: 0; box-sizing: border-box;}

 
        a { color: rgba(255,255,255,0.6); text-transform: uppercase; text-decoration: none; line-height: 42px; }
 
        h1 {padding: 50px 0; font-weight: 400; text-align: center;}
         
        .main {margin: 0 auto;}
        .main .quizsection {margin-bottom: 20px;}

        img {
            height: 300px;
            width: 750px;
        }
        div {
            width:1200px;
            margin: 0px;
            padding: 0px;
        }
        .correct {
            background: #5EB97D;
        }
        .incorrect {
            background: #EB6465;
        }
        label:hover {
            font-weight: bold;
            transition: 0.1s;
        }
        img:hover {
            height: 400px;
            width: 1000px;
            transition: 1.7s;
        }
        p { 
            display: inline; 
            font-size: 26px;
        }
        button {
            height: 40px;
            width: 200px;
        }
        input {
            height: 20px;
            width: 30px;
        }
        input.reset {
            height: 40px;
            width: 200px;
        }
    </style>
    </head>
    <body style="font-size: 22px;">
        <section class="main">
        <form name="quiz" action="javascript:check();" class="quizform">
            <div class="quizsection">
                <h2>Вопрос 1. В каком случае водитель совершит вынужденную остановку?</h2> <br>
                <div class="answer">
                    <input name="q1" value="value1" id="value1" type="radio" checked="checked" /><p> 1. Остановившись непосредственно перед пешеходным переходом, чтобы уступить дорогу пешеходу.</p>
                </div>

                <div class="answer">
                    <input name="q1" value="value2" id="value2" type="radio"/><p> 2. Остановившись на проезжей части из-за технической неисправности транспортного средства.</p>
                </div>

                <div class="answer">
                    <input name="q1" value="value1" id="value3" type="radio"/><p> 3. В обоих перечисленных случаях.</p>
                </div>
            </div>
            <br><br>
            
            <div class="quizsection">
                <h2>Вопрос 2. Разрешен ли Вам съезд на дорогу с грунтовым покрытием?</h2>
                <img src="фотки для билетов\awwXb55.jpg">
                <br>
                <div class="answer">
                    <input name="q2" value="value2" id="value1" type="radio" checked="checked" /><p> 1. Разрешен.</p>
                </div>
                <div class="answer">
                    <input name="q2" value="value1" id="value2" type="radio"/><p> 2. Разрешен только при технической неисправности транспортного средства.</p>
                </div>
                <div class="answer">
                    <input name="q2" value="value1" id="value3" type="radio"/><p> 3. Запрещен.</p>
                </div>
            </div>
            <br><br>

            <div class="quizsection">
                <h2>Вопрос 3. Можно ли Вам остановиться в указанном месте для посадки пассажира?</h2>
                <img src="фотки для билетов\udoJCL0.jpg">
                <br>
                <div class="answer">
                    <input name="q3" value="value2" id="value1" type="radio" checked="checked" /><p> 1. Можно.</p>
                </div>
                <div class="answer">
                    <input name="q3" value="value1" id="value2" type="radio"/><p> 2. Можно, если Вы управляете такси.</p>
                </div>
                <div class="answer">
                    <input name="q3" value="value1" id="value3" type="radio"/><p> 3. Нельзя</p>
            </div>
            <br><br>

<div class="quizsection">
                <h2>Вопрос 4. Какие из указанных знаков запрещают движение водителям мопедов?</h2>
                <img src="фотки для билетов\SZKoDrt.jpg">
                <br>
                <div class="answer">
                    <input name="q4" value="value1" id="value1" type="radio" checked="checked" /><p> 1. Только А.</p>
                </div>
                <div class="answer">
                    <input name="q4" value="value1" id="value2" type="radio"/><p> 2. Только Б.</p>
                </div>
                <div class="answer">
                    <input name="q4" value="value1" id="value3" type="radio"/><p> 3. В и Г.</p>
                </div>
                <div class="answer">
                    <input name="q4" value="value2" id="value4" type="radio"/><p> 4. Все.</p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <input class="reset" value="Отмена" type="reset" onclick="refreshPage()" />
        <button>Проверить</button>
 
    </form>
    </section>
    </body>

    <script type="text/javascript">
    var result;
    
    function check() {
  
       var question;
       var value1;
       var value2;
        
        
       question = 1;
       value1 = 0;
       value2 = 0;
       var u; 
        
       result = "";
  
       var choice;

        
       for (question = 1; question <= 4; question++) {

          var q = document.forms['quiz'].elements['q'+question];
  
             for (var i = 0; i < q.length; i++) {
                if (q[i].checked) {
                   choice = q[i].value;
                }
             }
  
             if (choice == "value1") {
                value1++;
             }
  
             if (choice == "value2") {
                value2++;
             }
          }
        
        for (u = 0; u <= 4; u++)
             if (value2 == u) {
          result = u + " правильный(ых)";
       }
       alert(result);
  }

    function refreshPage(){
        window.location.reload();
    } 

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', docReady);

function docReady() {
    document.getElementsByTagName('button')[0].addEventListener('click', showCorrectAnswer);
}
function showCorrectAnswer()
{
    for (question = 1; question <= 4; question++) {

    var l = document.forms['quiz'].elements['q'+question];
    
    if(document.querySelector('input[type=radio]:checked').value == 'value2') {
        document.querySelector('input[type=radio]:checked').nextElementSibling.style.backgroundColor = 'green';
    }
    else {
        document.querySelector('input[type=radio]:checked').nextElementSibling.style.backgroundColor = 'red';
        document.querySelector('input[value=value2]').nextElementSibling.style.backgroundColor = 'green';
    }
}
}

    </script>
</html>
```

разметка JS:

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', docReady);`


function docReady() {
    document.getElementsByTagName('button')[0].addEventListener('click', showCorrectAnswer);
}
function showCorrectAnswer()
{
    for (question = 1; question <= 4; question++) {
 
    var l = document.forms['quiz'].elements['q'+question];
    
    if(document.querySelector('input[type=radio]:checked').value == 'value2') {
        document.querySelector('input[type=radio]:checked').nextElementSibling.style.backgroundColor = 'green';
    }
    else {
        document.querySelector('input[type=radio]:checked').nextElementSibling.style.backgroundColor = 'red';
        document.querySelector('input[value=value2]').nextElementSibling.style.backgroundColor = 'green';
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Дополните ваш вопрос. Добавьте вашу разметку HTML, для которой должен работать данный JS код

Comment: разметку HTML добавил